# jQuery fade in effect on my home-made lightbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, fadein, effect

I don't really know how to solve this problem. I have this image. It is a thumnail picture, and when someone clicks on it, the bigger picture pops up. Please don't tell me I should use a downloadable lightbox, this is just perfect for me, except I want a fade in effect also when someone clicks on it, not just the popup thing.

```
    <a href="javascript:void();" onclick="document.getElementById('image1').style.display='block'; document.getElementById('image1_lightbox').style.display='block';">
    <div class="thumbnail"><img src="image1.jpg" /></div>
    </a>
    <div id="image1" class="underlay" onclick="document.getElementById('image1').style.display='none'; document.getElementById('image1_lightbox').style.display='none';">
    </div>
    <div id="image1_lightbox" class="lightbox">
    <a href="javascript:void();" onclick="document.getElementById('image1').style.display='none'; document.getElementById('image1_lightbox').style.display='none';">
    <div><img width="100%" height="100%" src="image1" /></div>
    <div style="padding-left:6px; padding-bottom:8px; text-shadow:0.1em 0.1em #eee;">Some text asdasdasdasd.</div></a>
```

And this is my CSS (lightbox and underlay classes):

```
.underlay{
display:none;
position:fixed;
top:0;
left:0;
width:100%;
height:100%;
background-color:#000;
-moz-opacity:0.5;
opacity:.50;
filter:alpha(opacity=50);
}

.lightbox{
display:none;
position:fixed;
top:100px;
left:25%;
width:50%;
z-index:100000;
background-color:#fff;
box-shadow:0px 0px 10px 5px #161616;
text-decoration:none;
}
```

Comment: pls post the code in jsfiddle

Comment: Never used jsfiddle before, I hope it's good - http://jsfiddle.net/bbz2S/

Comment: how about JQuery fadein function, have you tried that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use fadeIn() method from jQuery : http://jsfiddle.net/WTPUj/

```
<a href="javascript:void();" onclick="$('#image1').fadeIn(); $('#image1_lightbox').fadeIn();">
<div class="thumbnail"><img src="image1.jpg" /></div>
</a>
<div id="image1" class="underlay" onclick="document.getElementById('image1').style.display='none'; document.getElementById('image1_lightbox').style.display='none';">
</div>
<div id="image1_lightbox" class="lightbox">
<a href="javascript:void();" onclick="document.getElementById('image1').style.display='none'; document.getElementById('image1_lightbox').style.display='none';">
<div><img width="100%" height="100%" src="image1" /></div>
<div style="padding-left:6px; padding-bottom:8px; text-shadow:0.1em 0.1em #eee;">Some text asdasdasdasd.</div></a>
```

fadeIn method documentation : http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/